# How to Get the Next value from a string in c#?

Tags: c#, string

I have this API Response as a string.

```
/subscriptions/5e5c4cca-75b4-412d-96a1-45a9446ef08c/resourcegroups/ft-us-point-dev/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/ftadfqpb/providers/Microsoft.ResourceHealth/availabilityStatuses/current
```

Response object look like this :

```
{
            "id": "/subscriptions/5e5c4cca-75b4-412d-96a1-45a9446ef08c/resourcegroups/ft-us-point-dev/providers/microsoft.purview/accounts/ft-ue-pdc-dev-purview/providers/Microsoft.ResourceHealth/availabilityStatuses/current",
            "name": "current",
            "type": "Microsoft.ResourceHealth/AvailabilityStatuses",
            "location": "eastus",
            "properties": {
                "availabilityState": "Unknown",
                "title": "Unknown",
                "summary": "We are currently unable to determine the health of this Azure Purview.",
                "reasonType": "",
                "occuredTime": "2022-05-24T08:10:58.4372995Z",
                "reasonChronicity": "Transient",
                "reportedTime": "2022-05-24T08:10:58.4372995Z"
            }
```

Now, I need each and every value from this response.
For Example,
subscriptions value as 5e5c4cca-75b4-412d-96a1-45a9446ef08c,
resourcegroups value as ft-us-point-dev,
providers value as microsoft.datafactory,
factories value as ftadfqpb

How can I store these value so if in future if the api response has one or more values , my code is not affected by that.

Comment: Google for `c# string tokenizer`

Comment: Can you give an example of response object/describe the format?

Comment: That's JSON.  Use a JSON serializer to deserialize to some appropriate data model.  See e.g. [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6620165/3744182).

Comment: That i know. I need to get all values from field id only.

Comment: Recent versions of LINQ (.NET 6+) have `.Chunk()`, which allow this to be easily achieved: `id.Split("/").Skip(1).Chunk(2).Select(s => (key: s[0], value: s[1]))`. Going through `UriBuilder` so you don't break on things like query parameters or escaping (if applicable) is left as an exercise.

Comment: Your question is too vague. You show json data, but from the rest of the question it seems you only want to parse what's in the ID field in a very specific way. Please ask a detailed complete question about what you want to achieve, showing what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: In your example you have two `providers` piece of information. How do you want to handle that ?

Comment: I tried this code but getting null values only.

Comment: Can ignore last providers. Not relevant

Comment: @SakshamSrivastava Are you looking something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dAogbA

Comment: This answer seems to be working.. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Building on [@Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert)'s idea:

```
var pairs = 
   @"/subscriptions/5e5c4cca-75b4-412d-96a1-45a9446ef08c/resourcegroups/ft-us-point-dev/providers/microsoft.purview/accounts/ft-ue-pdc-dev-purview/providers/Microsoft.ResourceHealth/availabilityStatuses/current"
      .Split('/', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
      .Chunk(2)
      .Select(s => (key: s[0], value: s[1]))
      .ToList();
```

Gets you a list of pairs. It can't be a dictionary as there are two `providers`. You should be able to do some more with that list though to get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Consider parsing to an `XElement` object which offers the advantage of providing the means to act on the values received:

```
XElement xel = new XElement("id");
var id = deserialized.id;
var parse = id.TrimStart(new char[]{'/'}).Split('/');
for (int key = 0; key < parse.Length; key+=2)
{
    var value = key + 1;
    if (key < parse.Length)
    {
        xel.Add(new XElement(parse[key], parse[value]));
    }
    else System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false, "Mismatched pair.");
}
```

Test runner:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace json_model
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Model deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(json);

            // [Prelim] Requires further testing
            XElement xel = new XElement("id");
            var id = deserialized.id;
            var parse = id.TrimStart(new char[]{'/'}).Split('/');
            for (int key = 0; key < parse.Length; key+=2)
            {
                var value = key + 1;
                if (key < parse.Length)
                {
                    xel.Add(new XElement(parse[key], parse[value]));
                }
                else System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false, "Mismatched pair.");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(xel.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine();

            // An XElement is simple to search on and iterate.
            Console.WriteLine("Processing:");
            foreach (var element in xel.Elements("providers"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"'{(string)element}' is a Provider");
            }
        }
        class Model
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, string> properties { get; set; }
        }

        const string json = @"{
            ""id"": ""/subscriptions/5e5c4cca-75b4-412d-96a1-45a9446ef08c/resourcegroups/ft-us-point-dev/providers/microsoft.purview/accounts/ft-ue-pdc-dev-purview/providers/Microsoft.ResourceHealth/availabilityStatuses/current"",
            ""name"": ""current"",
            ""type"": ""Microsoft.ResourceHealth/AvailabilityStatuses"",
            ""location"": ""eastus"",
            ""properties"": {
                ""availabilityState"": ""Unknown"",
                ""title"": ""Unknown"",
                ""summary"": ""We are currently unable to determine the health of this Azure Purview."",
                ""reasonType"": """",
                ""occuredTime"": ""2022-05-24T08:10:58.4372995Z"",
                ""reasonChronicity"": ""Transient"",
                ""reportedTime"": ""2022-05-24T08:10:58.4372995Z""
            }
        }";
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
var responseId = "/subscriptions/5e5c4cca-75b4-412d-96a1-45a9446ef08c/resourcegroups/ft-us-point-dev/providers/microsoft.purview/accounts/ft-ue-pdc-dev-purview/providers/Microsoft.ResourceHealth/availabilityStatuses/current";
var parts = responseId.Substring(1).Split("/");
var results = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for(int keyIdx = 0; keyIdx < parts.Length; keyIdx += 2)
{
    if(!results.ContainsKey(parts[keyIdx]))
        results.Add(parts[keyIdx], parts[keyIdx + 1]);
}
```

1. Either call `.Split('/').Skip(1)` or `.Substring(1).Split('/')` to get rid of the leading `/`
2. Iterate through the `parts` by incrementing the loop variable with 2
3. If the key is already present ignore that key-value pair
4. Otherwise put the key value into the `results` collection